# How to grap a JSON-LD

Tags: d3.js, graph, json-ld

Is there a way (a library) to draw a Graph using as input a JSON-LD?

So far I have seen some D3 graphs but they are JSON based leaving metadata out.
This project does some work using LD, but it is a tree, not a graph. https://github.com/scienceai/jsonld-vis

Note: The LD is very important.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What metadata do you want to see that jsonld-vis does not display?

Comment: Hi, jsonld-vis is a tree. I'm looking for a graph. Edited the question thank you